# Where can i find different brush textures for texture painting?

Tags: texture-painting

The basic brushes in blender are cool and stuff but i sometimes want to add extra detail and if i could use different brush styles when texture painting game assets, it would come in really handy. any ideas on where i can find them and how i can install them?

Comment: Your question is about brushes, but what you need are brush textures, usually referred to as 'alphas'. You can create your own with Gimp or Blender or you can search online for them, depends on the type you want to use for your purpose. How to use them also depends on what you want to do, as there are several ways to use them in a single brush in Blender.

Comment: For texture painting

Comment: Yes, for texture painting - what do you have in mind in your question? Do you have an example of what you need to know?

Comment: For example, I want to add scratches or dents, marks, dirt etc on stylised objects. Not realistic ones though.